# As a developer: how can I prevent the a browser from storing credit card data?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, payment, cc

I am testing a Virtual Terminal application currently under development. I have noticed that the browser states that *Automatic credit card filling is disabled because this form does not use a secure connection*. That's true; I am currently not under a secure connection because I'm running the application locally. However, the final version will be published on a secure connection, so the browser will allow that feature.

How can we turn that feature off from the application itself? As a virtual terminal, the credit card numbers that will be stored in the browser will belong to the customers, not to the user of the application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you disable browser Autocomplete on web form field / input tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag)

Comment: Maybe. I was reading through that question and saw a lot of discussion about user login fields. These are credit card fields though. We have credit card fields for the sale and the refund. Autocompletetype is off in both, but Chrome ignores that for the sale screen. The difference is that the one in the refund screen only asks for the refund amount and the credit card number while the one in the sale screen also requests the cardholder name, expiration date, cvv, and zip code. It seems that Chrome recognizes this pattern and automatically tries to save the credit card information.